# Does Orion Context Browser works with BigData GE?

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to develop an application using FIWARE technology. This applications would use data from weather stations and weather models, among others. As far as I know, Orion Context Browser allows the creation and edition entities and it's data as attributes. My question is, in the case of being using large amounts of data, is it possible to use BigData Analysis GE together with the Context Browser to query real time data from meteo stations and data from weather models? Could the Orion Context Browser deal with this kind of data without using the BigData GE? Or viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

Orion Context Broker integration with Cosmos Big Data is done through [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/master/flume), a connector in charge of persisting the real time context data managed by Orion in data files at Cosmos' HDFS. This way, Orion manages the last value for certain entity's attribute, while Cosmos manages the historic about all the values sucg entity's attribute has had along time.

Anyway, it seems your application has other needs. If I've understood well, you are talking about querying weather models (which have been generated by using Big Data techniques) through Orion API (and/or Context Browser)... This cannot be done, at least natively. Nevertheless, the solution could be the following one: (1) inject your real time context data (weather events) to Orion as usual, (2) then connect Orion with Cosmos by means of Cygnus and create the historical view of your data. (3) In a regular way, generate the weather models using MapReduce or whatever other Big Data technique you may consider and finally (4) inject the weather models following the entity-attribute model of Orion in order it can be queried.